# Command-line approach to develop RAW images with Adobe XMP sidecars

Tags: raw, batch, adobe-camera-raw

For the purpose of automated and unassisted batch-processing (using `bash` and GNU `make`) I need a command-line tool to develop jpgs from my raw+xmp files.

I am on OS X and have the complete Adobe tool chain available (Lightroom 4, Bridge 5, Photoshop 5), however, have not yet found a way to interface to them from the command line; the answer to [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16293/is-it-possible-to-export-photos-from-lightroom-from-the-command-line) indicates that, at least for Lightroom, this is not yet possible. On Mac OS X it might be implementable via some crazy (and brittle) UI scripting, but Adobe products are generally not open to that as well because of their very specific UI toolkits.

I certainly would prefer developing via the Adobe engine, but if this is not possible, I would also go for another engine given that it – at least to some degree – applies the development settings stored in the XMP sidecars.

I know about [`dcraw`](http://www.cybercom.net/~dcoffin/dcraw/) (Open Source) and Apple's [`sips`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sips.1.html), but as far as I understand they would not apply the (Adobe) development settings stored in the XMP sidecars. But maybe there is some conversion tool available?

Any further suggestions?

Comment: Why not go the Lightroom-API way, using Lua? You should be able to execute these Lua scripts using bash and then the possibilities are endless, surely.

Comment: @Unapiedra: Sounds complicated, but feasable. Do you have an example for sich a Lua script that could be taken as starting point?

Comment: I think using a non-Adobe engine will be a non-starter. It's easy to see, for example, that Clarity is set to +20, but unless someone else implements the same Clarity algorithm, that's not going to help. And I doubt anyone can do that, for both technical and intellectual property reasons. And starting with Process 2012, even the simple-sounding adjustments (Exposure, Blacks, Whites...) are complicated image-adaptive algorithms, much like HDR tone mapping operators.

Comment: @coneslayer: Well, in the end it is a trade-off decision. For me, being command-line scriptable is more important than perfect quality. If the quality is okayish, it might be a starter.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Lightroom (not so sure about Photoshop and rest) does not support command-line-scripting. You can easily write plug-ins and there are numerous resources to help you ([SDK Guide](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/photoshoplightroom/pdfs/lr4/lightroom-sdk-guide.pdf), [Lightroom SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshoplightroom/sdk/eula_lr4.edu.html)). But according to a thread on the [Adobe-Forums](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/428398), calling a script that executes a specific Lightroom action does not work from the command line.

A pity, really.